# JSX mapping arrays stored inside a dynamic object (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

I'm new to React/Next and having some difficulty displaying data returned by an API.

Here is the data's structure:

```
myBooks = {
  reading: [
    {
      title: 'book1',
      cover: 'cover1.jpg'
    }
  ],
  toRead: [
    {
      title: 'book2',
      cover: 'cover2.jpg'
    }
  ],
  read: [
    {
      title: 'book3',
      cover: 'cover3.jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'book4',
      cover: 'cover4.jpg'
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I'd like the data displayed:

**Reading:**
book1

**To Read:**
book2

**Read:**
book3
book4

I'd like this to be dynamic, so if I add another category like "favorites," those books show in their own section with a relevant header.

And here is my attempt to render this data, using nested `.map` functions:

```
{Object.keys(myBooks).map(category => {
    <h3>{category}</h3>
    category.map(book => (
        <p>{book.title}</p>
    ))
})}
```

My rationale:

1. `.map` can't be used on an object, so I start by selecting the object's keys, which is what I call `category` (reading, toRead, read)
2. Once I display the category, traverse down and list each book associated with that category

**The error I am receiving:**
*TypeError: category.map is not a function*

Suggesting that category is not an array, or does not exist. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The category variable will be a string - `reading, toRead, and read`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead, this will give you access to each element's key and value.

```
{Object.entries(myBooks).map(([category, books]) => (
    <>
        <h3>{category}</h3>
        {books.map((book) => (
            <p>{book.title}</p>
        ))}
    </>
))}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. the function inside the first map, must return just one JSX element.
2. category is the key, so to get the value use : myBooks[category]
3. `category.map((book) => <p>{book.title}</p>);` is a js statement, it must be between {}, and remove the semi-colon at the end.

```
{Object.keys(myBooks).map((category) => (
        <>
          <h3>{category}</h3>
          {myBooks[category].map((book) => (
            <p>{book.title}</p>
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the category variable will be each key, which is a string. You should change the category.map to `myBooks[category].map()`

```
{Object.keys(myBooks).map(category => {
    <h3>{category}</h3>
    {myBooks[category].map(book => (
        <p>{book.title}</p>
    ))}
})}
```

Also, in this case, you don't want to use `.map()`. `.map()` is used when you want to modify the elements in the array - in this case, you just want to loop through them. Use `.forEach()` instead

```
{Object.keys(myBooks).forEach(category => {
    <h3>{category}</h3>
    {myBooks[category].forEach(book => (
        <p>{book.title}</p>
    ))}
})}
```